# Decrement the push badge count

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Need some advice as to how do we decrement the badge count once the notification is read. The badge count is incremented every time a push message is send from the server(badge count logic is at the server). Once the message is read at the device  and a new push message is not sent from the server how do we decrement the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the notification record from server end and you are using model for getter and setter , that time you should take one more boolean key IsRead that indicated that notification message is read or not and when showing the notification count check all IsRead key and show according to that :

that would help you to show the read and unread notification message count, its help me, please apply this logic;